# How to initialize robot's position in RVIZ?

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Nav2d simulator where in RVIZ the robot's position is set to X=0 and Y=0 I want to initialize the position to other coordinate for each time when I start the launch file.

I have been looking in tutorial2.rviz file and changed some of parameters but it didn't changed the position. I'm wondering if the robots position is not set in the tutorial2.rviz file then, the program start the position by it self in x=0, y=0.

So my question is where can I find the "parameter name" for x and y position of robot where I can add in tutorial2.rviz file?

I'm appreciating help since it will solve many of my problems.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232001/how-to-initialize-robot%27s-position-in-rviz-?/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found it! Robot's position in Rviz can be changed in  tutorial.yaml file.

---

Originally posted by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) with karma: 81 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-02**:
This doesn't answer the question of *how* to set the initial pose. It just states that it's possible. How did you go about solving your problem?